# Put variable values in an asynchronous function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

I implemented the image download function.

However, I found that the UI was stalled and I had the function asynchronous.

"(value) in" Passes the value safely, but if code try to put the value in a global variable, it will not be executed.

Code:

```
var arr = 0

ImageDownload(url: urll!) // asynchronous function
{   (value) in  // value = Image Height
    DispatchQueue.main.async
        {
            arr = value 
        }
}

// I want use this line
print("\(arr)")   // always print 0
```

ImageDownload Function :

```
func ImageDownload(url urll: URL, completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void)
{
    let queue = DispatchQueue.global()
    queue.async
        {
            if let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(urll as CFURL, nil)
            {
                if let imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil) as Dictionary?
                {
                    let pixelHeight = imageProperties[kCGImagePropertyPixelHeight] as! Int

                    if pixelHeight >= 2000
                    {
                        completion(pixelHeight/6)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        completion(pixelHeight/5)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Plz help me

Comment: arr should be strong, not weak, not optional.

Comment: Every thing in above code is correct just  Make sure value return by ImageDownload is not nil,

Comment: can you add your ImageDownload func

Comment: I added ImageDownload func

Comment: Where is `arr` `nil`? (Or do you mean it is 0, since it isn't an optional).  Are you attempting to access `arr` before the network operation has completed?

Comment: When out of ImageDownload (url: urll!), The value of arr is initialized to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using/printing `arr` value outside the block and before block execution.
Try moving print statement inside completion block

```
ImageDownload(url: urll!) { (value) in
  // value = Image Height
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    arr = value
    print("\(arr)")
  }
}
```

I mean perform your operation only after `arr` assignment
You can use `didSet` of `arr` too.

```
var arr = 0 {
  didSet {
    // Add your code here you want to execute after value assignment to `arr` 
    print("\(arr)")
  }
}
```

Comment: I did not completely solve it, but I got some direction.